# How to check the value which my program returns?

Tags: c, linux, shell

i have created a program in C. I would like to know, how to check the value which my program returns ... I mean, at the end of the code my program return zero if no error occurred. If an error occurred my program should return 1. And that's the problem, i want to see if really 1 is returned if something went wrong.
For memory leaks, etc I am using valgrind on Linux.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: use `echo $?` to check program return value.

Answer (score 6):

You can just print the special shell variable `$?`, e.g.:

```
$ ./my_program ; echo "status = $?"
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess you are looking for `$?`

call your program in a script and check the return value using `$?`

```
$?---it actually check the return code of the previously executed statement.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple

Use `echo $?` on your terminal just after exexcution of your program.

It gives the return value of previously executed command

e.g.

```
./my_program.out  // execution of program 
echo $?    // checking the return value , printing on terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

normally you don't have to consider the specific return code, you can use the shell logic to detect if something non-zero has been returned.

Just to print a message if failure was returned
./myprog || echo "Something went wrong"

or

only run myprog2 if myprog1 returns success
./myprog1 && ./myprog2